# Directive on Dynamically Rendered Input Element in Angular2+

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

**I'm trying to insert HTML Input Element on button click inside div container. I have created a directive & added the directive on the child input elements. Whenever I click on the input element, that element should be removed from the DOM.**

**I'm able to achieve this behavior but whenever I click on one HTML Input Element, then all the HTML Elements are removed from the DOM which is not expected.**

So, How to get single html input elementref in directive ?
app.component.html

```
<div class="btn-container">
  <button (click)="addInputElement()">Add Input</button>
</div>
<div class="box-container">
    <input deleteDir *ngFor="let el of inputEl; let i = index" id={{i}} [value]=el.value>{{el.value}}/>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   inputEl = [];
   addInputElement() {
     this.inputEl.push({value: Math.random()});
   }
}
```

app.directive.ts

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, 
            private renderer: Renderer2) { }


@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.renderer.removeChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode,this.elementRef.nativeElement)
}
```

Comment: Where you are applying the directive in your component?

Comment: @Obaid I have updated the input html tag. The directive is deleteDir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your use case and the code you provided looks fine to me. I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jehjls?file=src/app/app.component.css) for it, you can check this out. When I click on one `input` element, only the one I clicked gets removed.

#### Update

I have updated my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jehjls?file=src/app/app.component.css) from above. Now the input fields get deleted one by one if you press a key. Basically what I have done is to pass an index to the directive

```
HTML

<...>
    *ngFor="..."
    delete      <-- directive
    [index]="i" <-- input parameter in directive
</...>
```

```
DIRECTIVE

@Input()
index: number;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

@HostListener("input")
onInput() {
   this.renderer.removeChild(
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode,
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector(
      `[id="${this.index}"]`
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You ! Yes working for Input element, but for keypress event all the child divs are getting removed from DOM. I mean, If I select the particular div and click on delete button , then all the child divs are removed. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Ah you are talking about they keypress, let me check that as well. You should update your initial question, as keypress was not part of it.

Comment: I have adapted by example, it now works with any event being done in the input field